# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200b' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, regex

Why am i getting that error for this code section:

```
assert response == str_list_answers[elements_counter],\
                "{} != {}".format(
                str_list_answers[elements_counter],
                response)//error message on this line
```

**EDIT:**
Any clue how i can make that regex work,what i tried and didn't work out:

the issue definitely has to do with \ being a special character

`response = re.sub('\u200b', '', response)` i want it to remove `\u200b`

Comment: You should seriously consider learning Python 3, which has much saner Unicode handling. Besides, Python 2 will reach its official End Of Life in 2020. In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Will look into it, but for now can you suggest a way to fix it.

Comment: A simple way to fix it is to explicitly encode your Unicode text to ASCII, rather than using the automatic conversion. That way you can tell the encoder to ignore non-ASCII characters. Eg, `s = u'some\u200btext'; z=s.encode('ASCII', 'ignore'); print z` prints `sometext`. But if you don't want to throw away non-ASCII chars, you should be encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Any clue how i can make that regex work the issue definetly has to do with \ being a special character response = re.sub('\u200b', '', response) i want it to remove \u200b

Comment: You don't need regex for this, but you should not put Unicode chars into plain Python 2 string literals. The proper way to write that string in Python 2 is `u'\u200b'`.

Comment: Seriously, you need to learn how to handle Unicode correctly. As well as looking at the Ned Batchelder link I posted earlier, you should read the [Unicode HOWTO])(https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) from the Python 2 docs, and also Joel's article [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 0):

There are 128 characters in ASCII. The character you are trying to encode (the zero-width space) is not one of them.

Comment: zero width space? as in regular space?

Comment: @user9148659 No, the regular space doesn't have zero width, and its codepoint is U+0020, not U+200b.

Comment: well which character is it if you want to type it, this error is odd.

Comment: How to type depends on a lot of things such as which OS you're on. A common way to figure this out is to google. Among the top results for me is http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm which includes information about how to produce this character in (some versions of) Windows. Given a web page which contains it in a box, you can of course always simply copy and paste it. In Python, `print('*\u200b*')` might produce this character between two asterisks for you to copy/paste locally, but again, whether this actually works depends on a number of factors.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, something like this happens if strings you are trying to put in format() (str_list_answers[elements_counter] and response in your case) have this character. It can happen if one of them is a result of parsing some external content (text files, webpage and such).

Check str_list_answers[elements_counter] and response and make sure they don't contain this character. Example:

```
s = 'bla' + u'\u200b'    
print s.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
```

You should see this printed:

```
bla\u200b
```

When you find this character, just remove it before you put it into format().

Comment: You were right then i tried response = re.sub('\u200b', '', response) any clue how i can make that regex work the issue definetly has to do with \ being a special character

Comment: Try response = re.sub(u'\u200b', '', response). u before '\u200b' means unicode character.

Comment: Did not work - after doing response = re.sub(u'\u200b', '', response), are you still getting the unicode error message as before?